# Default arrow continues to appear when customizing ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I've completely customized `ExpandableListView`, but default group indicator (arrow) still appears. Here are my screenshots:

[image: collapsed]
[image: expanded]

Any ideas how to remove this arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setGroupIndicator(null);
```

should help